# Meteor: Maintain live counts for different views of collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to create a messaging app in Meteor (using the auth branch). It has a Messages collection, where each document has an array of reply documents ("replies"). In the sidebar we have different Views of the messages collection, where each view has a "query" field, which is supplied as an argument to the Meteor.publish('messages')... method.

So far so good. If I click on a view, the main part of the page displays a list of messages which match the query. For each message, I show it in bold if there are any replies that are newer than the last time the current user opened the message, or if she has never opened the message. I do this by maintaining a "read_by" field for each message, which contains an array of {user_id, ..., read_at: ...} records. This works beautifully too.

The problem is that I need each view in the sidebar to show a badge with the number of unread messages (as per the logic in the previous paragraph) for each view, not just the currently selected one.

How can I solve this? As far as I can tell, it means that I need to maintain a number of live queries against the Messages collection. At the same time, it is not an option for the client to subscribe to the entire Messages collection - let’s assume that it holds millions of documents. The client must remain snappy no matter how many documents are in the DB collection on the server.

I suspect that this requires a different schema design (which is not a problem), but I can’t quite see it.

Comment: No, it’s more like an email app than a chat app, so the counts need to reflect the state in the DB. We’ll keep every message and reply in the DB forever, unless they are manually deleted.

Comment: and these are shared messages (among many users) and I assume "feedback" has to be real time as they read through messages?

Comment: Yes, the messages are shared (within an account), so we can’t simply mark a message as read - it has to be marked read for a certain user at a certain time. And yes, I was hoping everything could be realtime. This is Meteor, after all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two options.

The easier option (which is perhaps not the most efficient) is to subscribe to all the different queries you are interested in:

```
 _.each(queries, function(query) {
   Meteor.subscribe('messages', query);
 })
```

And when you need the messages, use the same query to select only the ones you are interested in:

```
 Template.queryView.messages = function() { 
   return Messages.find(queries[Session.get('currentQueryNo')]);
 }
```

Obviously, you can then do the counts you need.

The other alternative would be to publish a special counts collection, which is manually setup. First, do something very similar to the `counts-by-room` example in the [publishing](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) section of the docs, then client side, do something like:

```
 var Counts = new Meteor.Collection('counts');
 _.each(queries, function(query) {
   Meteor.subscribe('counts-by-query', query);
 })
```

Each subscription to `counts-by-query` will maintain one record in the counts collection.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Once I fully understood the counts-by-room example, I went with your second alternative, and it works quite well. I guess my question had two components, the other being how to design my schema to be able to construct a query that finds all unread messages for a given view/user combo, but this was the main issue, so I’m marking your answer as the correct one. Thanks again!

Comment: Right. I was just imagining that you specify the query in such a way as it only gets a count of unread messages. Something like `{read_by: {$ne: user._id}}`. I'd have to play with mongo to tell you if you need to change your schema. Probably if you post a separate mongo question you'll get a much more expert answer than I can give you.